# SQLAlchemy scoped_session: Best approach of getting it to views

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, decorator, webapp2

I am creating a web application using WebApp2, SQLAlchemy, Apache, PostgrSQL etc. I have a `config` file which stores the database credentials and create the session object using scoped_session. Right now all my view files import this config file and use the session object like this:

```
some_view.py
import config

def view():
   query = config.session.query(bla bla)
```

This approach is not the final one and I want to use the best possible method.

What I want to achieve here is some way of getting the session object using a ***decorator or webapp2*** related inbuilt method so that after the execution of view function the session object is closed. I tried many ways but not able to achieve it. A working snippet will be highly appreciated.

If anyone having a better approach please suggest.

Thanks

Edit -----

@javex: Thanks for suggestion. I am looking for a decorator class which upon calling will return a scoped_session object and when the work is completed, closes the session. For your reference here is a sample code but it does not work.

```
class GetDBSession(object):
    """Decorator class to create DB session object"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=database_engine))

    def __exit__(self): #Dont know if it works
        self.session.close()

    def __call__(self): #Dont know if it works
        return self.session
```

And I want to use it like this:

```
@GetDBSession()
def view_func():
    #work with session object here
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about WebApp2 much but from what I get is that you want something that commits at the end of request processing and rolls back if there was an exception instead. There are some solutions out there form which you can adapt.

First of all, I suggest you read [When do I construct a Session, when do I commit it, and when do I close it?](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it). It has a paragraph about two extensions for framework integration that are particularly useful:

- [zope.sqlalchemy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.sqlalchemy)
- [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/)

These integrate SQLAlchemy into the zope transaction and flask frameworks respectively. After all, what you want is to build something around request processing:

```
try:
    result = handle_request(request)
    config.session.commit()
except:
    config.session.rollback()
    raise
```

This will only commit if there is no exception, else it will rollback and pass the exception along. How to integrate this depends on WebApp2 and how it allows this integration. Many frameworks offer some kind of "before-handle-after" approach like above: You get a callback that will process the request, you can do stuff before it, then call the callback and then do stuff after it. This allows for this neat try/except wrapper.